# Good and free program for SD card partitioning

Tags: windows, memory-card

Do somebody know free program for partitioning with many features **(recognising NTFS, FAT, FAT32, ext2, ext3, ext4, exFAT etc. creating and deleting partitions, moving and resizing them etc.)?**

Windows 8.1. It would be best to be free but if I have to pay so for 20$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give a try  [GNOME Partition Editer (GParted).](http://gparted.org/livecd.php)

GParted Live is a small bootable GNU/Linux distribution for x86 based computers.

**Features**

GParted enables you to easily manage your disk partitions:

- Create partition tables, (e.g., msdos or gpt)
- Create, move, copy, resize, check, label, set new UUID, and delete partitions
- Enable and disable partition flags, (e.g., boot or hidden)
- Align partitions to mebibyte (MiB) or traditional cylinder boundaries
- Attempt data rescue from lost partitions

GParted works with the following storage devices:

- Hard disk drives (e.g., SATA, IDE, and SCSI)
- Flash memory devices, such as USB memory sticks, Solid State Drives (SSD's), and Non-Volatile Memory Express devices (NVMe's)
- RAID Devices (hardware RAID, motherboard BIOS RAID, and Linux software RAID)
- All sector sizes (e.g., devices with 512, 1024, 2048, 4096 byte sectors and more)

Note: You might need a card reader in order to perform the partitioning more comfortably on pc.

Credits

1. [GNOME Partition Editor](http://gparted.org/livecd.php)